# Merge two data frames together that have the same variable names and data types

Tags: r

I have tried the `merge` function to merge two csv files that I imported. They both have the same variable names and data types but each time I run merge all that I get is an object that contains the names of the two data frames. I have tried the following:

```
# ex1
obj <- merge(obj1, obj2, by=obj)
# ex2
obj <- merge(obj1, obj2, all)
```

and several other iterations of the above.

Is merge the correct function?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am guessing that you actually want to `rbind` the data.frames, rather than merging them?

Try:

```
obj <- rbind(obj1, obj2)
```

`merge()` is really used to do the equivalent of a `JOIN` in SQL.

Comment: Right, and to expand on that, if df1 and df2 share the same column names, merge(df1, df2) will actually return just those rows that are identical between the two dfs! Which is definitely not what you wanted, OP!