# Appending data in R

Tags: r, dataset

I am producing a script where I have done many manipulations to a bunch of data and, I do these same manipulations to another dataset. Both data sets have the same rows, columns, and headers. I would like to be able to join the two data sets together where I place dataset A above dataset B. I wouldn't need to headers for dataset B and would instead just clump all of the data together as if they were never really separated in the first place. Is there a simply way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040352/merge-two-data-frames-together-that-have-the-same-variable-names-and-data-types and Joris posted a few more related questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141588/join-two-or-more-data-frames-in-system-r

Comment: Thanks Andrie for pointing that out. I will make sure to look more carefully beforehand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. Use `rbind()` command.

```
combineddataset = rbind(dataset1, dataset2)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it normal for rbind to forma matrix after using it to combine 2 data.frames?

Answer (score 3):

And for completeness, you could also use the `rbind.fill` function found in the `plyr` package.